# index xxxxxxxxxx beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have a piece of code that is crashing with:

> index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds for empty array

I know am supposed to check for the array to be empty first but I am not sure how.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathSecondLast = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[mArrChatDetails count]-1 inSection:0];
    ChatDetail *objChatOnCellSecondLast = [mArrChatDetails objectAtIndex:indexPathSecondLast.row];
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The **array** is **empty**. And 0 - 1 is `Int64.max` (18446744073709551615)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when `[mArrChatDetails count]` is 0 - i.e. when your table or collection is empty (I'm assuming that the context for this is something like a UITableView or UICollectionView).

Obviously you can only access the second-to-last element when there are at least 2, so this should be wrapped in an `if (mArrChatDetails.count > 1) { ... }` block.